# Is there a way to make a user only view related objects to him in a model in django administration?

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

I'm new to django and i'm trying to make a school web app fully inside the django administration.

The thing i'm trying to do is to make a permission for the students that gives them the ability to only see the `scores` which its `student` field is same to the student user.

This is my Student model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    student_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True)
    student_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    student_class = models.ForeignKey(Clas,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    student_idnum = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

And this is my students Score model:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    score = models.FloatField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.score)
```

I have seen the `Meta` model which i should use it for the custom permission, but i really don't know what should i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) has an example that does what you want.

> The get_queryset method on a ModelAdmin returns a QuerySet of all model instances that can be edited by the admin site. One use case for overriding this method is to show objects owned by the logged-in user

```py
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

You can change the queryset to fit your needs.